# Clicking text of radio button to register value

Tags: html, css

I had this working in Brackets, but when I switched over to Sublime Text I am no longer able to click on both the button and text to register he input.

```
 <form id = 'form'>
         <div class='btn' ><input id = '1' class='btn btn1' type="radio" name="1" value="" ><label for = '1' class="label1"></label></div>
        <br>
      <div class='btn'><input id = '2' class='btn btn2' type="radio" name="1" value="" ><label for = '2' class="label2"></label></div>
        <br>
      <div class='btn'><input id = '3' class='btn btn3' type="radio" name='1' value='' ><label for = '3' class="label3"></label></div>
        <br>
         <div class='btn'><input id = '4' class='btn btn4' type="radio" name='1' value='' ><label for = '4' class="label4"></label></div>
        <br>
      <input class = "click" id="submit" type='submit' name='1' value='Think you got it?  Click here to find out!'>
        <br>
  </form>
```

I would like to eventually be able to click on their entire div element for each button to register the input.

Comment: Having an empty `<label>` tag is nonsense.

Comment: I'm adding text via jQuery.  Hence the empty tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `<div>` tag, use `<label>` tag, and that's what's the use of it. Change the following:

```
<div class='btn' ><input id = '1' class='btn btn1' type="radio" name="1" value="" ><label for = '1' class="label1"></label></div>
```

To this:

```
<label class='btn' ><input id = '1' class='btn btn1' type="radio" name="1" value="" ></label>
```